# Finite Field Question

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

I'm having trouble with the Concept of finite fields. Say $\mathbb{F}_2 = \{0,1\}$. How many linear maps from $\mathbb{F}_2^5 \to \mathbb{F}_2^5$ (mapped from five tuples to five tuples) are injective? I know that the null has to be zero, but I'm thinking there might be an infinite number of maps.

I also had another follow up question. So now suppose $U = \{(x,x,y,y,y)\}$ where $x,y\in \mathbb{F}_2$. Using the same mapping, how many linear maps have their null space contain $U$ and equal $U$?

Comment: There are only $2^5=32$ five tuples of elements of $\Bbb F_2$, so there cannot be an infinite number of maps.

Comment: Do you really mean curly brackets of $U$? Because as a set, $U$ is just $\{x,y\}$. If you meant a $5$-tuple, you should use parentheses, not curly brackets. Also, please use MathJax to typeset your post.

Comment: ok yes I changed it

Comment: @Ross Millikan oh ok that makes sense. But not every one of them is injective right?

Comment: Choose a basis for $\mathbb{F}_2^5. $ Then your maps can be represented by $5 \times 5$ matrices whose entries are $0$'s and $1$'s. Your vector space is finte dimensional, so injective is equivalent to invertible. What condition about the matrix deteminant must be satisfied?

Comment: Observe that a map from a *finite* set to itself is injective iff it is surjective, so to look for injective maps in your case is the same as looking for bijective maps.

Comment: Definitely not. A map takes tulles to tulles, so there are more than $32$ of them. Then you demand that the map be linear, so there are fewer. I believe that makes it a vector space.

Comment: @Ross Millikan is it possible to list them all out by hand? Or is there a pattern

Comment: Like Chris Leary said, choose a basis and work from there

Answer (score 3):

Each linear map $A: \mathbb{F}_2^5 \to \mathbb{F}_2^5$ corresponds to a unique $5\times 5$ matrix with entries in $\mathbb{F}_2$. There are $2^{25}=33554432$ such matrices. This immediately rules out the possibility that there are an infinite number of maps $A: \mathbb{F}_2^5 \to \mathbb{F}_2^5$ (injective or otherwise).

By the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem), each *injective* linear map $A: \mathbb{F}_2^5 \to \mathbb{F}_2^5$ corresponds to a unique matrix in the general linear group $GL(5, \mathbb{F}_2)$. The
[order of the group is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group#Over_finite_fields)

$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(2^n - 2^k) &= (2^5 - 1)(2^5 - 2)(2^5 - 4)(2^5 - 8)(2^5 - 16) \\ &=31 \cdot 30 \cdot 28 \cdot 24 \cdot 16 = 9999360
\end{align}\tag1
$$

which means that $\frac{9999360}{2^{25}} \approx 29.8\%$ of the matrices in $\mathbb{F}_2^{5\times 5}$ correspond to injective maps.

The formula $(1)$ captures the fact that the first column of an invertible matrix in $\mathbb{F}_2^{5\times 5}$ can be anything but the zero vector, the second can be anything but the zero vector and the first column, the third anything but any of the four linear combinations of the first two columns and so on.

Comment: ok thank you so much. And for my second question, I am also confused on how to find that.